# ajax or html error on mozilla?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, firefox, mozilla

The web site was built on asp.net platform. Ajax enabled. It works very well on
ie or chrome, but it does not work on mozilla...?
You see arrows work great but the numbers does not appear?
how can i fix..

http://dexiab-2.hosting.parking.ru//Default.aspx#world the link to see the detail..
[image]

Comment: Sounds like a CSS glitch, but impossible to tell w/o code...

Comment: @Sir I sent you an e-mail due about the url.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is the label tag that you use, **change the label to span** (or div), and probably its going to work.

Comment: @it did not work Sir... But you are right sir I have to find  something else to present the data... you see the old static version of the web page used div, I changed the label to div, now it does not work.. http://blgnkl-2.hosting.parking.ru/index-OLDPAGE.html

Comment: @blgnklc Lost you :) now its work or not ? Double check it, if you change it to div, and still not work, then next think is to check if the PageMethods.GetData is called and return data on firefox. Just add a simple alert box on the return of this function to see whats happens there.

Comment: @Sir I double Checked it. The data comes I have seen since the arrows are changing according to data comes every five minutes.. The weird thing is the html version which has a link shown above, have div, and shows the data.. I will double check again. But untill that time if anything appears please tell me sir. Thanks

Comment: @blgnklc The firefox say:Warning: Use of captureEvents() is deprecated. To upgrade your code, use the DOM 2 addEventListener() method. For more help http://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM:element.addEventListener
Source file: http://dexiab-2.hosting.parking.ru//Default.aspx#world